# Unable to add Parallelism Task

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

How do I add task parallelism for this code? I have added in several places but it is not running as expected.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>PizzaTask());
    }

    static async void PizzaTask()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        int totalPizza = 10;
        Console.WriteLine($"Started preparing {totalPizza} pizza");
        for (var x = 1; x <= totalPizza; x++)
        {
            //Task.Run(() => MakePizza(x));
            await MakePizza(x);
        }
        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine($"Finished preparing {totalPizza} pizza");
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

    }

    static async Task MakePizza(int n)
    {
        PreparePizza(n);
        await BakePizza(n);
    }

    static void PreparePizza(int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start preparing pizza " + n);
        Thread.Sleep(5000);// synchronous
        Console.WriteLine("Finished preparing pizza " + n);
    }

    static async Task BakePizza(int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start baking pizza " + n);
        await Task.Delay(15000); // asynchronous 
        //Thread.Sleep(15000); // synchronous 
        Console.WriteLine("Finished baking pizza " + n);
    }
}
```

The working version before this is in BakePizza, I set to async await. But if I set async await for PizzaTask(), it doesn't work.

Comment: "*but it is not running as expected*" we don't know what you expect

Comment: Are you sure you want to just fire and forget `PizzaTask` ?

Comment: I think we should clear something up first. Tasks are not threads and async is not parallel

Comment: oh, I think I got it. Should be just `Task.Run(() => BakePizza(n));`. But after adding that, the elapsed time doesn't improve. hmm...

Comment: `PreparePizza` is synchronous. If you want to parallelize it then you need multiple chefs(cores), one for each pizza. Is your machine equipped with 10 cores?

Comment: Yeah, but BakingPizza can be asynchronous right? The requirement is while baking pizza, chef can start to prepare another pizza. I'm still trying to figure what is `ConfigureAwait(false)` and why it is used but not `ContinueWith`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've changed the code to make it async using Parallel loop via `var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, totalPizza).Select(i => MakePizza(i));`

- The below code invoke the `MakePizza` parallelly instead of sequentially via `for (var x = 1; x <= totalPizza; x++)
      {
          //Task.Run(() => MakePizza(x));
          await MakePizza(x);
      }`
- Used `Task.Delay` instead of `Thread.Sleep` to make sure the current thread is not blocked.
- Change the Code from `async void` to `aysnc Task`. The `async+void` combination can crash the system and usually should be used only on the UI side event handlers.
- As mentioned by @Steve, use `ConfigureAwait(false)` to return to any available thread instead of forcing context to return the caller thread.

Updated Code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
       PizzaTask().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task PizzaTask()
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        int totalPizza = 10;
        Console.WriteLine("Started preparing " + totalPizza + "  pizza");

        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, totalPizza).Select(i => MakePizza(i));
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks).ConfigureAwait(false);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Finished preparing " + totalPizza + "  pizza");
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + stopwatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

    }

    static async Task MakePizza(int n)
    {
        await PreparePizza(n).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await BakePizza(n).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    static async Task PreparePizza(int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start preparing pizza " + n);
        await Task.Delay(5000);
        //Thread.Sleep(5000);// synchronous
        Console.WriteLine("Finished preparing pizza " + n);
    }

    static async Task BakePizza(int n)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Start baking pizza " + n);
        await Task.Delay(15000); // asynchronous 
        //Thread.Sleep(15000); // synchronous 
        Console.WriteLine("Finished baking pizza " + n);
    }
}
```

You can check the output of code in dotnetfiddle -- https://dotnetfiddle.net/HepavC

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. By the way, the cook need to finish preparing pizza first, then only can bake but while baking pizza, cook can start to prepare another pizza. So, in this case, we should use ContinueWith instead?

Comment: @Steve - I agree we should use `ConfigureAwait(false)`. I've updated the code.

Comment: seems like the Select in this line got syntax error `var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, totalPizza).Select(i => MakePizza(i));`. It says `The type arguments for method 'Enumerable.Select<TSource, TResult>(IEnumerable<TSource>, Func<TSource, TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly`

Comment: I have changed to and it works now  `var tasks = Task.Run(() => Parallel.For(1, totalPizza, i =>
              
                  MakePizza(i)
              ));`

Comment: @Steve don't use `Parallel.For` with async delegates. This method doesn't understand them, and you end up with `async void` methods that cannot be awaited, and their exceptions cannot be handled.